# webpage accessibility

Tags: website, accessibility

i have a strange requirement. I want to access a page on my site through a link say **www.abc.com/downloads/file.txt** but i also want that if anybody enters only **www.abc.com/downloads** it should not be accessible or it should display access denied. How can i do that???????

Comment: "accessibility" often refers to features intended for people with physical limitations such as vision impairment.

Answer (score 1):

Disable directory browsing on your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Why make it inaccesible? That would be a problem if you ever have a bad link.

You can better create a index.htm file in /downloads that redirects to some custom error page, or to another page (like /downloads/file.txt).

It would work the same with only one question mark, also.